# QML: How to scale rotated Item around mouse point

Tags: qt, qml

I need scale and rotate a Rectangle around mouse point. When the Rectangle is not rotated my solution works fine, but if I apply Rotation transform I face the problem - my Rectangle move to an unexpected point. In my solution I use a MouseArea for drag the Rectangle, Scale and Rotation transforms for scale and rotate.

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: root
    color: "gray"    

    Rectangle {
        color: "black"
        width: 360
        height: 200
        opacity: 0.5
        x: 500
        y: 350
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: sample
        color: "green"
        width: 360
        height: 200
        opacity: 0.5
        x: 500
        y: 350

        property real currX: 0
        property real currY: 0

        property real currZoom: 1

        property real maxZoom: 5
        property real minZoom: 0.5

        transform: [
            Scale {
                id: scaler
                origin.x: sample.currX
                origin.y: sample.currY
                xScale: sample.currZoom
                yScale: sample.currZoom
            },

            Rotation{
                id: rotation
                origin.x: 180
                origin.y: 100
                angle: 30
            }
        ]

        MouseArea{
            id: mouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: sample

            onClicked: mouse => {
                           zoom(true, mouse.x, mouse.y)
                       }

            onWheel: (wheel) => {
                         var isIn = wheel.angleDelta.y > 0
                         zoom(isIn, wheel.x, wheel.y)
                     }

            function zoom(isIn, x, y) {
                var prevZoom = sample.currZoom
                var prevX = sample.currX
                var prevY = sample.currY

                sample.currX = x
                sample.currY = y
                sample.currZoom = calculateZoom(isIn, prevZoom)

                sample.x = sample.x + (prevX - sample.currX) * (1 - prevZoom)
                sample.y = sample.y + (prevY - sample.currY) * (1 - prevZoom)

                printSamplePostion()
            }

            function calculateZoom(isIn, prevZoom) {
                var newZoom = isIn ? prevZoom + 0.1 : prevZoom - 0.1

                if (newZoom > mouseArea.maxZoom)
                    newZoom = mouseArea.maxZoom

                if (newZoom < mouseArea.minZoom)
                    newZoom = mouseArea.minZoom

                return newZoom
            }

            function printSamplePostion() {
                console.log("== x: 500 y: 350 ======")
                console.log("-- x: " + sample.x)
                console.log("-- y: " + sample.y)
                console.log("=======================")
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: worked for me with `angle: 20` https://qmlonline.kde.org/

Comment: I see no code where you change the angle. Without trying the code, check this node from the Qt docs: _Each Transform is applied in order, one at a time_. Maybe you need to move Scale after the Rotation item?

Comment: Sorry,  yes Rotation item, now I set angel: 30

Comment: I've changed the order of Scale and Rotation, unfortunately it did not help.